# Redirect folder to subdomain and keep subdomain working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Iv'e got such a stupid question here but here we go:

I've got this url: http://www.mysite.com/subsite. I would like to use "/subsite" like this: http://subsite.mysite.com. This is easily achieved with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^subsite(.*) http://subsite.mysite.com$1 [L]
```

But here's the stupid part. All my links on my site is already like this: "http://subsite.mysite.com/content". In this case this url should be redirected to "http://www.mysite.com/subsite/content". This creates endless loops (of course).

```
RewriteRule ^subsite(.*) http://subsite.mysite.com$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/subsite/$1 [R]
```

Is it possible to achieve what i'm aming at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `mod_proxy` for this.

Then have rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !subsite http://subsite.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.com/subsite%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

Comment: Correct answer even though it was the other way around.